# Producer.send doesn't work inside of .map

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka

I'm making application that fetches data from elasticsearch and sends it to kafka. But producer.send() function does not work inside of map, however outside of it, everything works perfectly

```
val f1 = ElasticsearchSource
  .create(
    indexName = "products",
    typeName = "product",
    query = """{"match_all": {}}"""
  )
  .map { message: OutgoingMessage[spray.json.JsObject] =>
    val product = message.source
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord("test", product))
    println("publishing message ")
    IncomingMessage(Some(message.id), message.source)
  }
  .runWith(Sink.seq)
```

What might be the cause of it?

Comment: What is the error your getting?

Comment: I get no error message. It just doesn't send after timeout

Comment: `.map` is meant to convert data from one type to another, not iterate a collection with actions. If you get timeouts, 1) show the errors 2) sounds like a network issue at the Kafka side